# Error de sintaxis no capturada: expresión esperada, obtuvo '<' datatable

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, php7

**Alguien de esta comunidad ha tenido este error, ya depure mi codigo, pero no veo errores.
inlcuso cuando inspecciono el codigo me manda error en <!DOCTYPE**

[image: Error en la imagen]
[image: error al inspeccionar el codigo]

Buscando un poco mas, encontre hacia donde apunta el erro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando editas una pregunta en este sitio el código HTML que empieza por < debes acotarlo entre acentos graves `\`<blabla>\``, sino desaparece de la pregunta

Comment: @masterguru Cuando depuro mi proyecto me manda ese error, pero no tengo ningun problema con la funcionalidad, es por ello que no puedo dar mas informacion. es lo que pude visualizar cuando inspecciono el codigo.

Comment: @masterguru ya lo acabo de publicar la captura de donde me manda el error

Comment: Por la pinta que tiene, diria que datatables intenta recoger un dato de alguna parte, seguramente de /Prueba/vendor/datatables/ y se encuentra con ese HTML en lugar de una respuesta que el pueda entender y procesar, y por eso peta al encontrarse con un simbolo `<` que no espera

Comment: @masterguru seguire revisando a ver que puedo encontrar.